# How to use R to solve the multi whole unknown number equation

Tags: r

How to solve using R in the equation 43.5a + 21.5b +26.5c + 43.5d = 826 , for a,b,c,d is positive integer. I know that there will be a lot of solutions, but it is alright. Thanks.

Comment: You can just brute force for the result, there is no subtraction, and a, b, c, d are positive and upper-bounded.

Comment: It is much easier to do this outside R, for example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+43.5a+%2B+21.5b+%2B26.5c+%2B+43.5d+%3D+826+over+the+positive+integers

Answer (score 5):

This should work (not run):

1. You need to solve for any of the variables first.

   ```
   Solve.a <- function(b,c,d) {(826-21.5*b-26.5*c-43.5*d)/43.5}
   ```
2. You need to determine limits for looping. If they're all positive integers, `a` and `d` cannot be bigger than about 17 or so, while `b` and `c` cannot be larger than about 37.
3. Write a loop and use brute force:

   ```
   for(b in 1:37) {
       for(c in 1:37) {
           for(d in 1:17) {
               a <- Solve.a(b,c,d)
               if (a %% 1 == 0 & a > 0) print(c(a,b,c,d))
               }}}
   ```