# list all solutions for solving polynomial in r

Tags: r

I have a equation 50x+50y = 200, and I programmed in R as:

```
a = array(c(50,50),c(1,2))
b = c(200)
qr.solve(a,b)
```

but it turns out only show 4 and 0 as the result. So, my question is there a way to list all the solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ZheyuanLi so you mean I don't have the way to list all the integer solution ?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi how about positive integers? they are not infinite

Comment: More general setting for sure. I think there should be a way to list all the positive integer solutions, right? thank you for all your answers, but do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: you're probably going to need specifically an *integer linear programming* solution (not `qr.solve` at all, by the way ...) Don't know much about those methods, but that should help you search

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639147/how-to-use-r-to-solve-the-multi-whole-unknown-number-equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need non-negative integer solutions, you can do this easily by brute force since 0<=x<=4 and 0<=y<=4:

```
dd <- expand.grid(x=0:4,y=0:4)
with(dd,dd[50*x+50*y==200,])
##    x y
## 5  4 0
## 9  3 1
## 13 2 2
## 17 1 3
## 21 0 4
```

(ignore the first column, it's just the row numbers from the original data frame)